# Which toolbox item(s) can I use to manage database list?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Medication> Medications { get; set; }
    }

    public class Medication
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

What could I use to add/remove medications for each customer? I tried to create a CheckListBox but I could not save the checked items to the customer, are there other options to manage a list like this? I have created several medications but now I want to bind multiple to each customer

Comment: means you are asking about the window controls in which you can bind  multiple madication

Comment: Yes, which would be the best for that?

Comment: it depends what would you prefer listview on popup window, checkboxlist , open another window and show madication name with check box to add or remove

Answer (score 0):

One of many solutions to this is:

- Create split container (vertical)
- On left side create ListBox where you will disable multiselect
- On right side create CheckListBox

ListBox will hold `Customer Name` as display value and `Customer Id` as value member.

`OnSelectedItemChange` event inside `listBox` will handle medications for customer.

When you click some other customer, event run command which will firstly get `List<Medication>` for specific `Customer Id` and then show it on the right side.

Other handling of changes is pretty basic.

Once again, this question is opinion based and this is my opinion.